# Unpivot part of a record creating new records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to process stock information by day, but the database stores the info per week, using a column for each day.

I've tried using unpivot but I need to repeat first columns and create new records per day. I am not finding the right way to do it.

```
COUNTRY_CODE    COMPANY_CODE    ITEM_NBR    Department    Week    SUN_QTY    MON_QTY    TUE_QTY    WED_QTY    THU_QTY    FRI_QTY    SAT_QTY  
US    ING    5555    19    11731    19    19    19    43    41    40    22
```

The expected output should be like

```
COUNTRY_CODE    COMPANY_CODE    ITEM_NBR    Department  Week    Day QTY
US  ING 5555    19  11731   SUN 19
US  ING 5555    19  11731   MON 19
US  ING 5555    19  11731   TUE 19
US  ING 5555    19  11731   WED 43
US  ING 5555    19  11731   THU 41
US  ING 5555    19  11731   FRI 40
US  ING 5555    19  11731   SAT 22
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution (that works across all RDBMS) is to use a series of `UNION ALL` queries (one per day of the week), like:

```
SELECT
    country_code,
    company_code,
    item_nbr,
    department,
    week,
    'SUN',
    sun_qty
FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    country_code,
    company_code,
    item_nbr,
    department,
    week,
    'MON',
    mon_qty
FROM mytable
UNION ALL
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option

```
Select COUNTRY_CODE
      ,COMPANY_CODE
      ,ITEM_NBR
      ,Department 
      ,[Week]
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('Mon',MON_QTY)
                     ,('Tue',Tue_QTY)
                     ,('Wed',Wed_QTY)
                     ,('Thu',Thu_QTY)
                     ,('Fri',Fri_QTY)
                     ,('Sat',Sat_QTY)
             ) B([Day],Qty)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UNPIVOT works as follows:

```
select COUNTRY_CODE, COMPANY_CODE, ITEM_NBR, Department, Week,
case Day
when "SUN_QTY" then "SUN"
when "MON_QTY" then "MON"
when "TUE_QTY" then "TUE"
when "WED_QTY" then "WED"
when "THU_QTY" then "THU"
when "FRI_QTY" then "FRI"
when "SAT_QTY" then "SAT"
END,
Qty
from mytable
unpivot
(
Qty for Day in (SUN_QTY, MON_QTY, TUE_QTY, WED_QTY, THU_QTY, FRI_QTY, SAT_QTY)
) as newtable
```